# Perl: fork(), avoiding zombie processes, and "No child processes" error

Tags: perl, ipc

I have a Perl app that's been running largely untroubled on a RH system for a few years. In one place, I have to run a system command that can take take many minutes to complete, so I do this in a child process. The overall structure is like this:

```perl
    $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'; # Ignore dead children, to avoid zombie processes
    my $child = fork();

    if ($child) {    # Parent; return OK
       $self->status_ok();  
    } else {         # Child; run system command
         # do a bunch of data retrieval, etc.
         my $output;
         my @command = # generate system command here
         use IPC::System::Simple 'capture';
         eval { $output = capture(@command); };
         $self->log->error("Error running @command: $@") if $@;
         # success: log $output, carry on
    }
```

We recently changed some of our infrastructure, although not in ways that I expected would have any influence on this. (Still running on RH, still using nginx, etc.) However, now we find that almost every instance of running this code fails, logging 'Error running {command}: failed to start: "No child processes" at /path/to/code.pl'.

I've looked around and can't figure out what the right solution is for this. There was a suggestion to change `$SIG{CHLD}` from 'IGNORE' to 'DEFAULT', but then I have to worry about zombie processes.

What is causing the "No child processes" error, and how do we fix this?

Comment: You get zombie processes when the parent doesn't  `wait` on the child's exit code. What does `status_ok()` do? Does that exit the program? Wait for the child? You should probably handle SIG_CHLD; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608017/no-child-process-error-from-waitpid-when-waiting-for-process-group  may be helpful.

Comment: This is in a web framework; `status_ok()` basically sends a message to the front end saying "Your request is being processed; you should get e-mail shortly with full details" and then exits (we send e-mail when the child's system command is complete). We don't handle `SIG_CHLD` anywhere, and I'm not really sure how to. But again, this had been running for years with no problems until recently.

Comment: The comment should be changed to "Ignore dead children to ensure they become zombies"

Comment: If the parent typically exits after sending a response, then the child gets inherited by pid 1 and is immediately waited on.  If you're now getting zombies, it's because the parent is not exiting.  Probably it is blocking when attempting to send the response.

Comment: I would add some monitoring code.  In the parent, monitor the child with `kill 0, $child` and `ps`.  In the child, check the command before execution e.g. `ls -la $command[0]`.  Decode $? and $!. Try doing the spawn manually rather than with IPC::System::Simple.  Try IPC::Cmd.  Try manually running whatever `@command` contained at the shell prompt.  Try adding an `strace` in front of the command.  Commands failing to start can have bizarre causes.  Maybe you need to rebase.  Maybe a new library is hooking your process and breaking it. HTH.

Comment: I may well be misunderstanding some (most/all) of what's happening, but: As far as we can tell there are no zombies. We have the "No child processes" error but don't actually know what that means; we get this even immediately after restarting the webservers, when resources should be available. As for the parent waiting on the child's exit code: We don't want to do this at all, that's the whole point of forking: The parent has to return a "processing" message and then go away, while the child is still doing its thing. (continued)

Comment: And the parent doesn't seem to be blocking; at least, the front end gets the "processing" message, which suggests that the parent is successfully sending its response. Regarding monitoring, we did move to regular `system()`, or backticks; this had no effect. The itself command itself runs fine when run manually on the commandline, but of course the command never runs in the first place.

Comment: note that fork() returns "the child pid to the parent process, 0 to the child process, or undef if the fork is unsuccessful".  you really should check for error, not assume you are in the child when it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *There was a suggestion to change $SIG{CHLD} from 'IGNORE' to 'DEFAULT', but then I have to worry about zombie processes.*

This isn't true.

A zombie process is a process that has ended, but hasn't been reaped by its parent yet. A parent reaps its children using `wait`(2), `waitpid`(2) or similar. `capture` waits for its child to end, so it doesn't leave any zombie behind.

In fact, the error you are getting is from `waitpid`. `capture` is waiting for the child to end to reap it and collect its error code, but the you instructed the OS to clean up the child as soon as it completes, leaving `waitpid` with no child to reap and no error code to collect.

To fix this problem, simply place `local $SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT';` before the call to `capture`.

Comment: also, checking if fork failed instead of assuming false means you are in the child is a good idea

Comment: @ysth, Shouldn't that have been a comment to the OP? Anyway, there's obviously missing parts to the code (e.g. the lack of `exit` in the child), but I decided to simply answer the question rather than speculating about the OP's actual code. Similarly, the OP's code obviously needs a code review (e.g. the `use` statement in the middle of run-time code), but I didn't want to veer off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I did modify the code for simplicity's sake, and I apologize if it resulted in something confusing. The original does indeed have `CORE::exit(0);` in the child, and it doesn't actually have `use IPC::System::Simple` in the middle of the code, but I wanted to make it clear where `capture` was coming from without bothering to indicate that it's 300 lines above etc. In any event, this solution is working for me, so, thank you very much!

Comment: @ikegami fair enough